# django makemigrations not detecting new model

Tags: python, django

I used `makemigrations` earlier in order to make my Django app aware of the tables in my legacy MySql database, and it worked fine. It generated models.py. Now, I want to add a new **"UserDetails"** model to my app:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

After saving the file, I ran the following command in the command prompt:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

But `makemigrations` is not seeing the new class I wrote inside the models.py, as it always outputs 'No changes detected'

Am I doing it correctly or is there anything wrong with it? I checked my MySQL db and confirmed that no table named UserDetails already exists.

Comment: Do you have anything in the migrations folder? Also, which Django are you using?

Comment: may i  know where can i find migrations folder? thanks

Comment: It should be in your app folder `your_app/migrations`. Also as other people have suggested - make sure your app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: do i need to put the models.py inside the package? now it is lying under at  the same level as manage.py

Comment: Yes. You can use `./manage.py startapp <app_name>` to see how the apps usually look. If you are still having problems, paste your structure in your question so we can help you beter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models.py needs to be inside the application package, rather than in the main directory for the makemigrations to work.

Answer (score 41):

I've met this problem during development and this combination helps me:

```
python manage.py makemigrations mymodule
```

This command create migrations for the specific module. It should be in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but you'll get warning if it's not in there.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Also, mention answer by xiaohen, I've create packages with PyCharm, so I've got **init**.py file by default.

Answer (score 18):

I encountered similar issue ("No changes detected" when adding new models) when using Django 1.11, and solved by importing the new models (actually better to import all models) in the `__init__.py` in `models` package:

```
from .student import Student
from .teacher import Teacher
```

It's written here:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package

Comment: This will also work if you add the `import`s in the `__init__.py` in the folder containing the `admin` classes.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure your app is registered in the settings.py,
if so then try running:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations "app_name"
```

Comment: Docs on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps

Answer (score 3):

You have to run `python manage.py makemigrations` first, Second, you have to run `python manage.py migrate` to sync db.

If you `mkdir` a folder to save your model, you have to add it to `__init__.py`.

Comment: i have done that, it is saying 'no migrations to appy'

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you forget to register your app in setting.py file.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue may be if you have two ForeignKeys that point to the same model without a `related_name` to distinguish between them. E.g.

```
fk1 = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)
fk2 = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)
```

Django should give you a warning: `HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app.Model.fk1' or  'app.Model.fk2'.`

But I didn't see it until I restarted django.

Answer (score 1):

I want to also add apart from the answers provided above if problem still not solved, please do ensure your migrations dir is available in your app folder if not available ensure to create one and make sure to create an

> `__init__.py`

file inside so that python interpreter will be able to identify that the dir is python dir. Please edit if I might have misused some terminologies. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, note that when the `abstract` attribute is set to `True` in the models `Meta` class, the model will be ignored by makemigrations.

Check that the atrribute is set to `False` or remove it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add: If the model Meta class has an app_label, and it is different to the INSTALLED_APPS label - it will fail.